# Android new animations lollipop

Tags: android, animation, material-design

Why does not the animation ? I'm using a Nexus 5 Real Not an Emulator.

My build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "es.canada.victor.pomodoro"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

The button is INVISIBLE

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
     Utilities.showView(btAcept);
 }
```

And the animation method

```
   public static void showView(View myView) {

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    // make the view visible and start the animation
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();

}
```

Comment: Your code looks good so far and you should see the animation. Perhaps you could show us the rest of it so we could analyze further? (The code you use to initialize the button and also the one that starts the animation.)

Comment: Thanks!. I use a fragment. This is the code. http://pastebin.com/zjENrpXc